# In ReactJS, facing problem in rendering the data from an API due to its odd structure

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const [arrName, setName] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    
    axios.get('URL')
        .then( response => {
          // console.log( response.data )
          setName( response.data )
        });
    
  }, [])

  const foo = () => {
    console.log(arrName.data[0].data[0]._id)
    // following two console statements need not to be in the code. I am putting them only to show the structure of API

    console.log(arrName)
    console.log(arrName.data)
  }

  return(
    <div> 
      Hi,  I'm the component 
      <button onClick={foo}> console </button>    
    </div>
  ) 
}

export default App;
```

**Console response screenshot**

[image: Console response screenshot]

I want to simplify the following statement. So that I can easily iterate the API and print anything from the API. However, I am printing only an id here.

```
console.log(arrName.data[0].data[0]._id)
```

Following command breaks the code

```
<div>  
       arrName.data[0].data.map((item) => <li>{item._id}</li> ) }
 </div>
```

Kindly, Help me what changes should I make to my code.

Comment: How would you want to print? I mean the final expected result?

Comment: want to iterate it something like arrayName.map( itr => <li> itr._id </li>)

Comment: Please check my answer, see if it match your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Based on the replied comment, you would do it like so:**

```
arrName?.data &&
  arrName.data.map((item) => (
    <ul>
      {item.data.map((chidlItem) => (
        <li> {chidlItem._id} </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  ));
```

The `?` is [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which is to check if the reference in the chain is valid, so it will skip the map function if `arrName` or `arrName.data` is null/undefined

Comment: This code worked  but my code broke when i refreshed  the browser. Now getting an error -->  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Comment: wow, that is working. Thank you. Ryan can you please provide a little explanation.

Comment: Sure do. Give me a moment, I’ll update my answer with explaination

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just iterate this part?

`arrName.data[0].data`

```
for (const d of arrName.data[0].data) {
    console.log(d._id)
}
```

Comment: You should just ask the questions in the comment. You are asking the question in the answer

Comment: He has not got enough rep to put a comment, though

Answer (score 0):

I guess the real problem is from the backend API sending the data structured as an array of objects inside another array of objects. One solution could be saving the value needed in an array that would be more accessible to you.

```
const [arrName, setName] = useState();

useEffect(() => {

  axios.get('URL')
    .then( response => {
      // console.log( response.data )
      setName( response.data[0].data )
    });

}, [])
```

but that will only be a workaround.

Comment: My bad I should have mentionned that the code should change to:

<div>  
       arrName.map((item) => <li>{item._id}</li> ) }
 </div>